# Undefined variable: _SESSION [APP\Controller\UsersController.php in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp

```
Undefined variable: _SESSION [APP\Controller\UsersController.php in cakephp 2.0
```

Have included the **Session component** in to

```
UsersController var $components = array('Session', 'Cookie');
```

Code is that:

```
if(!empty($id))
{               
   print "<br><pre>";       
   print_r($_SESSION['text']);
   print "<br><pre>";
   print_r($this->Session->read("captchatext"));
   die;     
}  
else
{
   $_SESSION['text'] = "jjsssssjj";
   $this->Session->write("captchatext", "ddddddssssssssssdddd");
   print "ddddddssssssssssdddd";
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing direct and wrapper access to session? You should always use only the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

and why not you use cakephp syntax for reading the session like:

```
   print "<br><pre>";       
   print_r($this->Session->read('text'));
   print "<br><pre>";
```